# What do I have to change in my html/css to seperate the writing from the picture?

Tags: html, css, image

In the last couple lines I have an image and text on its right. Now I tried with the `padding-left` attribute and the margin attribute but non of them work.  I really wanted this to the right - now this is a team project but my partner is not really doing anything and he just copied and pasted the text and now I have to do something with it. This is the only this I could come up with.
Can someone find the error?

```css
body{
 margin-top:65px;
 height: 1500px;
}

#text {
 background-color:#FFF;
 float: center;
 margin-left: 250px;
 margin-top: 5px;
 width:810px;
 padding-bottom: 300px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 36px -4px rgba(97,97,97,0.47);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 36px -4px rgba(97,97,97,0.47);
 box-shadow: 0px 5px 36px -4px rgba(97,97,97,0.47);
}

#text p{
 font-family: verdana;
 font-size: 15px;
 padding-top:2px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 2px;
}
h2{
 font-family:  impact;
 font-weight:normal;
 font-size: 18px;
 text-indent: 25px;
 margin:0;
 padding-top:20px;
}
```

```html
<! doctype html>

<html>
 <head>
  <title>html/css helper</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
 </head>
 
 <body>
   
   <p><img src="pictures/aufbau.png" style="width:250px; height:230px;float:left; padding-left: 15px; padding-right:0;border:1px solid #cdcdcd"</p>
   </!-->
   
   <p style="padding-top: 30px;margin-left:20px;">html tags - umschließen den kompletten Inhalt </p>
   <p style="padding-top: 10px;margin-left:20px;">head tags - braucht man um Metainformation zu erhalten.</p>
   <p style="padding-top: 25px;margin-left:20px;">body tags - der Inhalt (und alle weiteren HTML-Befehle, die den Inhalt strukturieren)</p> <br/>
   
   <p>Im Gro&szlig;en und Ganzen ist das alles, was man braucht, um eine einfache Webseite zu konstruieren </p>
   
  </div>
 
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which picture are you talking about?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :)

Comment: Please edit your question to show only the code that is relevant to the problem you're describing.

Comment: @www139 thank you :) i'm talking about the second one - i change the code so it get's more clear which one i meant - thanks for the tip shaggy

Comment: @Abigail Could you please give us the exact class/id name of the picture that you are referring to to make it perfectly clear? Thank you :)

Comment: <img src="pictures/aufbau.png"> i did not give it a class/id i just wrote the style into the html document

Answer (score 0):

just remove    `position: fixed;` styling of an image will separate text and image

Comment: but the picture has no position: fixed;  attribute. I don't mean the picture on the right corner. I mean the last one on the page. @ganeshsatpute

Comment: float: right; padding-left: 0px; to last image will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Okay, totally been there. My sympathies.

Any way, is this what you want? I moved the

```
<img src="pictures/html_logo.png" style="width:150px; height:150px; float: right; right:0px; top: 50px;padding-bottom: 10px;  padding-top:20px; padding-right: 15px;">
```

Into the text div and removed `position: fixed;`

```css
body{
 margin-top:65px;
 height: 1500px;
}

#text {
 background-color:#FFF;
 float: center;
 margin-left: 250px;
 margin-top: 5px;
 width:810px;
 padding-bottom: 300px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 36px -4px rgba(97,97,97,0.47);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 36px -4px rgba(97,97,97,0.47);
 box-shadow: 0px 5px 36px -4px rgba(97,97,97,0.47);
}

#text p{
 font-family: verdana;
 font-size: 15px;
 padding-top:2px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 2px;
}
h2{
 font-family:  impact;
 font-weight:normal;
 font-size: 18px;
 text-indent: 25px;
 margin:0;
 padding-top:20px;
}


/* NAV MENU START */
#nav {
 height:42px;
 background-color:#222;
 position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(120,120,120,1);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(120,120,120,1);
 box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(120,120,120,1);
}

#nav_wrapper {
 width: 1185px;
 height:42px;
 margin-left: 350px;
 text-align: left;
}

#nav ul{
 list-style-type: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 position: relative;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

#nav ul li{
 font-family:monospace;
 font-size: 16px;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 align: center;
}

#nav ul li:hover{
 background-color: #333;
}

#nav ul li img{
 width: 11px;
 height:11px;
 vertical-align:middle;
 padding-left: 5px;
}

#nav ul li a,
#nav ul li a.visited{
 color: #ccc;
 display:block;
 padding: 10px;
 text-decoration:none;
}

#nav ul li a:hover{
 color: #ccc;
 text-decoration: none;
}

#nav ul li:hover ul{
 display: block;
}

#nav ul ul{
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #333;
 border: 5px solid #222;
 border-top: 0;
 margin-left: -5px;
 min-width: 80px;
 padding:0;
 padding-top: 8px;
}

#nav ul ul li {
 display: block;
}

#nav ul ul li a,visited{
 color: #ccc;
}

#nav ul ul li a:hover{
 color: #099;
}
/* NAV MENU END */

/* SIDEBAR START */
#sidebar{
 background-color: f1f1f1;
 position:fixed;
 width: 200px;
 height: 560px;
 float:left;
 margin-left: 5px;
 top: 60px;
}

#sidebar_wrapper{
 background-color: f1f1f1;
 position:fixed;
 width:200px;
 height: 560px;
 float: left;
 top:60px;
}

#sidebar ul {
 font-family:monospace;
 font-size:25px;
 list-style-type:none;
 text-decoration:none;
}
#sidebar li {
 font-family:monospace;
 list-style-type:none;
 text-decoration:none;
}
#sidebar ul li ul li a{
 list-style-type:none;
 text-decoration:none;
}

#sidebar_li ul {
 font-family: monospace;
 font-size: 18px;
 list-style-type:none;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-indent: -25px;
 padding: 7px;
 margin:0;
}

/* SIDEBAR END */
```

```html
<! doctype html>

<html>
 <head>
  <title>html/css helper</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
 </head>
 
 <body>
  
  <!-- NAVIGATION MENU </!-->
  <div id="nav">
   <div id="nav_wrapper">
    <ul>
     <li>
      <a href="home.html">
       <img src="pictures/home.png" alt="" style="width:19px;height:19px;vertical-align:middle;padding-right:13px;padding-left:13px;"/>
      </a>
     </li>
     <li><a href="html.html">HTML <img src="pictures/arrow.png" alt="" /></a>
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Intro</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Basic</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Tags</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Classes</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Intro</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Intro</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Intro</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="intro_css.html">CSS <img src="pictures/arrow.png" alt="" /></a>
      <ul>
       <li><a href="intro_css.html">Intro</a></li>
       <li><a href="basics_css.html">Basics</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Intro</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Intro</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Intro</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Intro</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 <!-- NAVIGATION MENU OVER </!-->
  </div>
  
  <div id="sidebar">
   <div id="sidebar_wrapper">
    <ul>
     <li>HTML</li>
      <div id="sidebar_li">
       <ul>
        <li><a href="bilder.html">Bilder</a></li>
        <li><a href="tabellen.html">Tabellen</a></li>
        <li><a href="text.html">Text</a></li>
        <li><a href="videos.html">Videos</a></li>
        
       </ul>
      </div>
     <li>CSS</li>
      <div id="sidebar_li">
       <ul>
        <li><a href="#">##</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">##</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">##</a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="text">
  <!-- alex's teil -->
<img src="pictures/html_logo.png" style="width:150px; height:150px; float: right; right:0px; top: 50px;padding-bottom: 10px;  padding-top:20px; padding-right: 15px;">
   <h2>Was ist HTML?</h2>
   <p>HTML ist eine plattformunabh&auml;ngige Dokumentbeschreibungssprache, 
   die kann man auf Deutsch als Auszeichnungssprache f&uuml;r Hypertexte 
   &uuml;bersetzen und die f&uuml;r Web-Seiten Herstellung und Strukturierung 
   geeignet ist. Das HTML-Dokument enth&auml;lt den zu &uuml;bertragenden 
   Text und zus&auml;tzlich HTML-Kommandos (Tags, Marken) zu seiner Formatierung, 
   Bilder, Querverweise auf andere Dokumente (Hyperlinks) oder auch T&ouml;ne, 
   animierte Bilder und Formulare f&uuml;r Eingaben.</p>
   
   <h2>Wie schreibt man HTML?</h2>
   <p>Es gibt viele verschiedene Programme, um eine Internetseite 
   herzustellen, aber die einfachste Variante ist, ein ganz Standardm&auml;&szligen
   Text Editor zu benutzen.</p>
   
   <p>Dabei ist es wichtig, darauf zu achten, in was f&uuml;r einem Dateityp man den HTML
   Dokument speichert. <br/></p>
   <!-- abigail -->
   <p><img src="pictures/html_speichern.png" style="width:665px;height:116px; padding-right:70px;padding-left:70px;padding-top:20px;padding-bottom:10px;float:middle;"></p>
   <p><img src="pictures/bulb_html.png" style="width:500px;height:40px;float:left;border:1px solid #dcdcdc;padding-top 10px;padding-right:290px;"></p>
   </!-->
   <h2 style="padding-top:60px;">Wie ist HTML aufgebaut?</h2>
   
   <p>Ganz am Anfang eines HTML Dokumenten m&uuml;ssen wir erstmals dem Browser
   sagen, was er &uuml;berhaupt bearbeiten muss. Im Fall eines HTML Dokumenten,
   machen wir das mit der Deklaration < !doctype html> <br/>
   <!-- abigail -->
   Das Eigentliche Dokument steht zwischen den html tags. In den html 
   tags stehen dann die head und body tags. In den head tags finden wir noch meta tags 
   und den Titel der Seite. Auch Schl&uuml;sselw&ouml;rter womit Suchmaschinen auf die 
   Seite kommen sollen werden in den head tags geschrieben. Nichts was in den head tags
   geschrieben wird sieht man auf der Website.
   </p>
   <p><img src="pictures/aufbau.png" style="width:250px; height:230px;float:left; padding-left: 15px; padding-right:0;border:1px solid #cdcdcd"</p>
   </!-->
   
   <p style="padding-top: 30px;margin-left:20px;">html tags - umschließen den kompletten Inhalt </p>
   <p style="padding-top: 10px;margin-left:20px;">head tags - braucht man um Metainformation zu erhalten.</p>
   <p style="padding-top: 25px;margin-left:20px;">body tags - der Inhalt (und alle weiteren HTML-Befehle, die den Inhalt strukturieren)</p> <br/>
   
   <p>Im Gro&szlig;en und Ganzen ist das alles, was man braucht, um eine einfache Webseite zu konstruieren </p>
   
  </div>
 
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `<p> </p>` and that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to but text and photo in the same row you have to make some thing like this

```
<style>
.sidebar{
    width:40%;
    float:right;
    margin:1%;
    text-align:center;
}
.therapy {
    float:left;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100%;
    height::auto;
    padding:1%;
}
.section{
    width: 29%;
    float:left;
    margin:2% 2%;
    text-align:center
}

</style>

--<Html code>---

<section class="left-col">
        <p style="text-indent: 50px;">FIFA President Sepp Blatter addresses a news conference at the FIFA headquarters in Zurich, Switzerland, June 2, 2015. Blatter resigned as FIFA president on Tuesday, four days after being re-elected to a fifth term. Blatter, 79, announced the decision at a news conference in Zurich, six days after the FBI raided a hotel in Zurich and arrested several FIFA officials.</p>
        <p style="text-indent: 50px;">Unfortunately, the page you were looking for doesnt exist, but you can try searching the website, or browsing through the content. Of course, you can always go back home and start from scratch.</p>
    </section>
    <aside class="sidebar">
        <div class="therapy">
            <img src="http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/therapist.jpg">
        </div>
    </aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

change img styling  `float: left;` `padding-left: 15px;` to  `float: right;` `padding-left: 0px;`